# How to prevent a function from adding repeated keys to a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Let be the follow function bellow. The function takes the elements line by line from a file and adds it to a dictionary (each line has a key and a value).

```
with open("archive.txt") as f:
      for line in f:
         (key, val) = line.split()
          dictionary[key] = val
```

Example: Let be the following .txt file:

```
aaa 111
bbb 222
aaa 333
ccc 444
```

Insert in the following dict:

```
dictionary = ['aaa':111, 'bbb':222, 'aaa':333, 'ccc':444]
```

however, I would like to prevent repeated keys from being inserted, so the end result should be:

```
dictionary = ['aaa':111, 'bbb':222, 'ccc':444]
```

How to prevent the insertion of a duplicate key?

Comment: Currently, if the key is a duplicate, the new value will overwrite the previously associated value to the key. Is that not acceptable?

Comment: What does "or item" mean? And where are your example input and output?

Comment: Adding to @HeapOverflow: Example input/output is an important part of a [MCVE]; in this case, it would help clarify intent where the prose description is somewhat ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to always keep the first value associated with a given key, a simple trick is to [use `setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to set the value *only* if the key doesn't already exist:

```
with open("archive.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, val = line.split()
        dictionary.setdefault(key, val)
```

`dictionary.setdefault(key, val)` is essentially equivalent to the somewhat more verbose:

```
if key not in dictionary:
     dictionary[key] = val
```

though (at least on CPython, though not necessarily all alternate interpreters) the former is atomic (when the key is a built-in type, e.g. `str` in this case), while the latter isn't (two threads could both perform the test, find no such key, then both insert, in arbitrary order, and both threads would believe they set the value, even though only the second to write would win).

If keeping the *last* value is what you want, then your original code is already fine; `dict`s only store one copy of a key, so replacing the associated value if it's reassigned, so your original code only keeps the last value already.

Comment: Don't even need those extra variables.

Comment: @HeapOverflow: Sure, `dictionary.setdefault(*line.split())` would work without needing `key` and `val` to be explicitly named/stored, but it would also be more confusing if a `line` didn't have exactly two space-separated values (with only one, it would silently associated `None` with the value, with three or more, it would die with a `TypeError`, where at least the split up lines dies with a somewhat more obvious `ValueError`).

Comment: Hmm, ok. Anyway, let's see what OP means with preventing adding duplicate "values" and "items"...

Comment: I guess there is also `dictionary[key] = dictionary.get(key, val)`, but that's not as nice as `setdefault()`.

Comment: @RoadRunner: Yar, that's logically equivalent (aside from the atomicity aspect), but needlessly stores the same original value over and over each time a duplicate key is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the dictionary contains the key before overwriting a key/value that's already there

```
with open("archive.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
     (key, val) = line.split()
     if key not in dictionary:
         dictionary[key] = val
```